# "Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : Forbidden (HTTP 403)" when using searchTwitter in R

Tags: r

I am trying to retrieve a selection of tweets  using the Twitter API in R using the following code:

```
appname <- "..."
    consumerkey <- "..."
    consumersecret <- "..."
    accesstoken = "..."
    accesssecret = "..."
    setup_twitter_oauth(consumerkey, consumersecret, accesstoken, accesssecret)

    tweets <- searchTwitter("GameStopStock", lang = "en", n = 100)`
```

I get an error after

```
  tweets <- searchTwitter
```

which is:
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) :
Forbidden (HTTP 403).`

what should I do?
it is very important for my thesis

thank you

Comment: what version of twitteR do you have installed? it could be a lot of things, not the least of which being your username/password are wrong, locked/disabled, or something else, or the package needs an update.

Comment: Note that musk locked most of twitter's APIs behind a paywall. It might be related to that.

Comment: I have a developer account and I have been approved for Academic Research access. Therefore I have the Twitter API v2.